# 'Method' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context, Error in Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire for network handling in swift and run into one weird error. It seems like we can't pass  **Method**  enum as parameter.
 [Error is on Method parameter]

[image]

```
private func apiRequest(method: Method, url: String, apiData: [String : AnyObject], completion:(finished: Bool, response: AnyObject?) ->Void) {

    Alamofire.request(method, url, parameters: apiData).responseJSON{ response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            completion(finished: true, response: JSON)
        } else {
            completion(finished: false, response:nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use qualified name, e.g. `Alamofire.Method` if there is a name collision. You are already doing that for `request` function.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You have to specify the module from which to lookup object type.
Call `Alamofire.Method`

Answer (score 18):

There is probably a name collision. To solve it, you can use the qualified name of the `enum` (including the module name):

```
private func apiRequest(method: Alamofire.Method, ...
```

Comment: Compared a diff and saw I had imported RealmSwift (which is chock full of name collisions...shame). Fixed it

Answer (score 8):

I have also encountered this problem, because I have declared a number of the same name of the protocol:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
   static func someTypeMethod()
}

protocol SomeProtocol {
   init(someParameter: Int)
}

protocol SomeProtocol {
   var mustBeSettable: Int { get set }
   var doesNotNeedToBeSettable: Int { get }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Had this error conflict when using "Moya" and when bridging a c framework, fixed it by implicitly adding `Moya.Method` module.

```
var method: Moya.Method  {
    switch self {
       case .login: return .post
       case .register: return .post
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The type `Method` is declared in two imported modules. You have to specify the module from which to use the type. Use `Alamofire.Method` instead of `Method`.

**Tip**: If you are using the type often, you can create a type alias in your module (application):

```
typealias Method = Alamofire.Method
```

That way you will not need to prefix the type with `Alamofire.` any more.

Comment: Unless both frameworks need to be used at the same time, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer to this did fix the build error; in my case, the file showing the warning was in two different frameworks so Xcode did not know where to look. This was not the intended behavior of our internal frameworks so I simply removed the copy I no longer wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a class declared in two or more places in your application. The error is saying that there is no conclusive way to use this class because there are a couple different places in the code it is declared.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 and Alamofire 4.7**

Replace `HTTPMethod` to `Alamofire.HTTPMethod`

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because my database table name and model class name was same...Issue resolved by renaming model class name.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem by deleting the Alamofire folder in the pods project manually. Then, I do a "pod install" to reinstall the missing pods.

There are significantly less files in the Alamofire folder after doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the enum type name to different &...

- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

Target - > building settings- >ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES, Value type is Boolean, click on the other, change the value to $(inherited)
perform - pod update
Done

then try to run Your project , error will gone ! (I have tried in my project)

enum 'XYZ'ButtonType {

}