# Xcode 8 beta 'Error' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8-beta6

According to this article, I need to specify the module to lookup object type:

['Method' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context, Error in Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543597/method-is-ambiguous-for-type-lookup-in-this-context-error-in-alamofire)

But the below function is call from Apple API. Should I wait until Xcode 8 is out of beta? Or am I missing anything?

> 'Error' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

function in **AppDelegate.swift**

[image]

Import section

[image]

Comment: Can you post the entire contents of this file, including your import statements? There's a good chance multiple imported modules provide an `Error` type, and you need to be specific about which one you want. Also, maybe the type signature has changed in iOS 10, but prior versions of this method used `NSError`, not `Error`.

Comment: Xcode 8 GM it is already available for download

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication,
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error)

Comment: Why is your method `@nonobjc`? That'll just conceal it from Objective-C, and therefore won't be called by the app delegate.

Comment: @CraigOtis thx for the response , I just add some infos to my question

Comment: Import Statement it is not the issue

Comment: @Hamish it was just a warning before add **@nonobjc** , but xcode wants me avoid this warning after add this

Comment: @LeoDabus  thx for notice , I am now downloading ..

Comment: even without `@nonobjc` , error still appear , it just avoid the warning show up

Comment: One of the modules you're importing has most likely defined its own `Error` type – you could use `Swift.Error` to disambiguate

Comment: @Hamish , mark my import module `Realm` and `RealmSwift` solve this problem ! Thx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Solution is to just type `Swift.Error` instead of `Error`.

The issue occurs when one of your modules has its own Error Type...:/

For example:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Swift.Error) {}
```

I hope this works for you :)

Comment: Thanks  for the response ! After Update to xcode 8 GM solved the problem

Answer (score 7):

The type `Error` is declared in two imported modules. You have to specify the module from which to use the type. Use `Swift.Method` instead of `Method`.

**Tip**: If you are using the type often, you can create a type alias in your module (application):

```
typealias Error = Swift.Error
```

That way you will not need to prefix the type with `Swift.` any more.