# 'Object' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios11

I want to update my app for iOS 11, and have this issue. This is my current code:

```
protocol DataSourceDelegate: class {
    associatedtype Object

    func cellIdentifierForObject(object: Object) -> String
    func swipeToDeleteObject(object: Object)
}
```

This protocol is used in one of my view controller:

```
extension TransactionsViewController: DataSourceDelegate {
    func cellIdentifierForObject(object: Object) -> String {
        return "Cell"
    }

    func swipeToDeleteObject(object: Object) {
        object.managedObjectContext?.performChanges {
            object.managedObjectContext?.delete(object)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I get this error for the `Object` type:

> 'Object' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

On this line:

```
func cellIdentifierForObject(object: Object) -> String { ... }
```

For my this issue appears because there are some other Object type in my project. I tried to put the protocol or class name in front of the name, but I still get error.

Comment: Having name conflicting classes is not a good idea. But if you've and if ambiguity arises then you should use full class name as `ModuleName.Object`. Do let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore: but in my case who is the ModuleName ? The name of the class ? Protocol ? or the module(directory) where my file exists ?

Comment: I added a typealias inside the class to specified exactly who Object is. Seems to work now.

Comment: The module name is the name of the project that your object class belongs to(Generally)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcode8 beta 'Error' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394514/xcode8-beta-error-is-ambiguous-for-type-lookup-in-this-context)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In my case, I had this ambiguity because the class was declared in a swift file and also being auto-generated by my data model.

If you already declare your class in a swift file, then make sure the code generation is disabled for it.

1. Select your entity in your xcdatamodeld
2. Open the third tab, Data Model inspector:
   [image]
3. Set Codegen to Manual/None
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

For me the cause of the error was same name of the Class for two different Cocoapods. If you are integrating pods to your VC, try to delete some of them by clearing 'Import ...' line at the top of your VC file.